# self join using cakephp

Tags: sql, cakephp-1.3

how can i write this sql query in cakephp

```
select name from coupons as c where c.created=(select max(c2.created) from coupons as c2);
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, maybe you actually mean this:

```
$this->Coupon->find('first', array('order' => array('Coupon.created' => 'desc')));
```

For real subqueries, [see the manual under **Subqueries**](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1030/Complex-Find-Conditions).